# How to use libavcodec in Qt4?

Tags: c++, c, qt4, ffmpeg

How do I use libavcodec in Qt4 to access individual video frames?

After verifying that the video stream can be decoded by libavcodec by compiling [this example](http://web.me.com/dhoerl/Home/Tech_Blog/Entries/2009/1/22_Revised_avcodec_sample.c_files/avcodec_sample.0.5.0.c), I moved the source code to my C++ program. Now `av_open_input_file()` is suddenly unable to open my video file (returning an errorcode: -2).

The call looks like this right now:

```
...
// Register all formats and codecs
avcodec_register_all();

// Open video file
QString videoFileName("/absolute/path/to/video.avi"); // from somewhere else in the application
const char* fileName = videoFileName.toStdString().c_str();
int err = 0;
if((err = av_open_input_file(&pFormatCtx, fileName, NULL, 0, NULL)) != 0)
{
    doErrorHandling(err, fileName); // err = -2
}
```

When I look at `const char* fileName` inside the debugger it looks correct. Am I making some basic mistake in mixing C and C++ code (for a first attempt I just dumped the code from the example into the constructor of a class)?

**Note**: In order to get the application to compile I include the headers like this:

```
extern "C"
{
#define __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS // for UINT64_C
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
}
```

I have also tried to hard code the path to the video file into the application without any success:

```
av_open_input_file(&pFormatCtx, "/home/bjoernz/video.avi", NULL, 0, NULL);
```

I was able to compile and execute the example (avcodec_sample.0.5.0.c) using `g++`.

Comment: const char* fileName = videoFileName.toStdString().c_str(); Avoid things like that. Your pointer is pointing to temporarys object internal data, so it may lead to strange errors, as memory to this pointer will be freed after ;. You should pass whole videoFileName.toStdString().c_str() as a parameter. Also, .toStdString may loose encoding, use .toLocal8Bit() instead (It return QByteArray, but QByteArray has overloaded (const char *) casting

Comment: Thank you, I was hoping for some advise like that. I get the file name now by calling `videoFileName.toLocal8Bit().constData()`. I assigned it to a variable before to make debugging easier.

Comment: You can't asign it to variable, because it is still temporary object. Remember that QByteArray is casting automaticly to const char *, so you may do just QByteArray fileName = videoFileName.toLocal8Bit(); and then pass it as parameter to av_open_input_file(&pFormatCtx, fileName, ...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is embarrassing:

When I transfered the source code from the example to the c++ application I made a stupid mistake when I got linker errors, that told me that `av_register_all();` was unavailable... and I renamed it to `avcodec_register_all()`, a little while later I fixed the linker problem and forgot about it...

**Solution**: `avcodec_register_all()` needs to be changed to `av_register_all()`.

Answer (score 2):

Error -2 means `No such file or directory`. I'm pretty sure the file you're attempting to open isn't located in your "current working directory" when running the application.

Comment: I admit that `QString videoFileName("video.avi")` is misleading. Normally `videoFileName`contains the absolute path to the desired file (I will clarify this in the question).