# FFMpeg sample program

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, ffmpeg

I am currently learning ffmpeg tutorial of Martin Bohme [Tutorial Here](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial01.html)

and I want to compile an ffmpeg sample program using Code Block IDE but, it can't

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "libavcodec/avcodec.h"
#include "libavformat/avformat.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
av_register_all();

    return 0;
}
```

Please help me. How to compile it. I am using Linux (Ubuntu)

Comment: What problems do you have? Please edit your question to add things like errors.

Comment: Compiler says can't find "libavcodec/avcodec.h" these is my problem. Or how to compile the sample program of Martine Bohme's sample program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to tell the compiler where the header and library files are. This is done by the [`-I`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) flag to tell which directories contain header files, and [`-L`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) to tell which directories contains libraries. You will also need `-l` to tell which libraries to link with.

The flags can be used like this:

```
$ g++ -I/path/to/headers myprogram.cpp -L/path/to/libraries -lthelibrary
```

A note about libraries: On Linux (and UNIX systems) they are files with names that start with "lib" and end with the extension ".a" or ".so". When specifying the library with the `-l` flag you do *not* write those. So for a library file "libfoo.a", you only use `-lfoo` to link with it.

For more information about the options of gcc and g++, see http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html.

**Edit:** For an IDE like Code::Blocks there most likely is some project setting where you can add include and library directories and link libraries. Check the "Project" menu for a "Settings" or "Properties" alternative.

**Edit2:** See for example [this](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=FAQ-Compiling_%28errors%29#Q%3a_My_build_fails_with_multiple_undefined_reference_errors.3F) FAQ where to find linker settings in Code::Blocks, the pre-processor settings should be close by.

Comment: g++ -I /usr/local/include main.c -L /usr/local/lib -lavcodec -lavformat 

says 

error: ‘UINT64_C’ was not declared in this scope

Comment: @Glennascual [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4184789/440558) question contains a code-snippet on how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

you can try following command to compile in Linux.

```
gss <program-name.c>
```

Answer (score -2):

For IDE like eclipse follow [FFMPEG - Eclipse Setup Guide[Linux] official](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Setup_Eclipse_IDE_for_FFmpeg_(Linux))

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being barely more than a link to an external site is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).