# C++: Writing images to video file independent of installed codecs

Tags: c++, video

I'm trying to save a series of images (16 bit grayscale pgm) as video. The video has to be compressed. My program has to be independent of the codecs installed in the system.

My initial idea was to use OpenCV for this, unfortunately it depends on codecs installed in the system (unless I'm missing something).

I feel like there should be a way to compile an encoder (H264 or similar would be perfect) into the program or redistribute it as a dll with my program. I just can't find any good up to date guidance/examples.

I've been swimming in the deep vast ocean of AV encoding for a couple of days and would really appreciate it if someone could point me to a right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: What about focusing on a specific codec first, and then attempt to encode videos using the [libav library](http://www.libav.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

As Ben suggests, it would be a good idea to use an established library in your code.

FFMPEG is probably the most used at the moment - it can be used on the command line, with a 'wrapper' program or the libraries it is built with can be used directly.

I think the last case sounds like the one you want - you can find documentation here:

- https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Using%20libav*

Note the comment about disambiguation at the start - this is important to understand as the project lib and the library (which is what you want) are different things.

and there is some notes in this answer on how to build it into a program:

- [FFMpeg sample program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015089/ffmpeg-sample-program)